# Getting categories from table if there's any service binded to the category id in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1
```

I would like to get results from categories if the "services" table has any data for that specific category id. I was thinking about Left join or something like that. Any suggestions? (I use PHP btw)

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` sounds like a good idea. What is the problem?

Comment: Giorgos Betsos solved the problem. Just what I needed!

Comment: Doing a sub-query for every row in your table is not very efficient; a `JOIN` with an `IS NOT NULL` check would probably be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT c.* 
FROM categories AS c
WHERE c.status = 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                               FROM services AS s
                               WHERE s.category_id = c.id)
```

Comment: Solved my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: @logiacer Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.